# Marklogic: stemming doesn't return satisfying results

Tags: xquery, marklogic, stemming

The stemming result for the following `cts:stem('motivation', 'en')` is `motivation`. I'm expecting the result to be `motivate`. how to solve this?

Answer (score 4):

According to http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/stemming:

> The stemming supported in MarkLogic Server does not cross different
>   parts of speech. For example, conserve (verb) and conservation (noun)
>   are not considered to have the same stem because they have different
>   parts of speech. Consequently, if you search for conserve with stemmed
>   searches enabled, the results will include documents containing
>   conserve and conserves, but not documents with conservation (unless
>   conserve or conserves also appears).

In your case: motivation is a noun, motivate is a verb.

Answer (score 2):

Your workaround here is to add terms to a custom dictionary (see http://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/custom-dictionaries) to give the stems you want.